# popupDIV obscuring ajax HTMLEditorExtender

Tags: ajax

I have three separate WebForms using Visual Studio 2015 with different complexities
They all contain Ajax HTMLEditorExtenders that were attached to textboxes set to textmode="multiline" and added in Designer Mode
In each of these I am encountering a non visible popupDIV obscuring some of the Toolbar buttons and text area and cannot find a way to dispose of this popup.
the popupDiv is centred on the screen.

I looked at the page using inspect element and when I change the CSS for opacity to '1' I can see the popup and exactly where it is overlapping my HTMLEditorExtender.

The popup is showing a Cancel button that is unselectable.

My markup I am using on the simplest of the pages is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"    MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"  CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.vb" Inherits="CRMDash2.WebForm2" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">       

<article>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <div class="contbox">
            <asp:textbox runat="server" textmode="multiline" ID="TextBox1" Rows="15" ></asp:textbox>
            <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender         ID="TextBox1_HtmlEditorExtender" 
runat="server" 
BehaviorID="TextBox1_HtmlEditorExtender" 
TargetControlID="TextBox1">
            </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</article>
</asp:Content>
```

The inspection of the element shows

```
<div class="ajax__html_editor_extender_popupDiv" id="MainContent_TextBox1_HtmlEditorExtender_popupDiv" style="opacity: 0;">
<div id="MainContent_TextBox1_HtmlEditorExtender_btnCancel" style="border: 1px solid black; top: 10px; width: 55px; padding-left: 20px; float: right; position: relative; cursor: pointer;" unselectable="on" float="right">Cancel</div>
</div>
```

My questions are "is this an Ajax bug? (can't find it on their site)and
What can I do to remove it as a work around??

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, add this to the css in your header.

```
.ajax__html_editor_extender_popupDiv {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Perfect Patrick, problem solved: Thanks so much. Solution is simple and effective. I appreciate your input